# Installing anchors into a hollow metal panel

Tags: anchor, curtain-rail

I'm installing a curtain rod in our studio. The windows we have are installed and framed by metal including a metal panel box atop them. It's hollow and the metal panel appears to be less than 2mm thick.

[image: The panel in question with one successfully installed anchor]

I see holes already from a prior tenant and I'm trying to utilize those.

[image: The anchors. (Manufacture supplied on top of the left case)]
Using the anchors supplied by the curtain rod manufacturer does not work. Tapping the anchor into the metal, it starts to impact on the surface and does not sit flush with the wall. There's no width specified by instructions but comparing with other anchors it looks to fit in 1/4" holes.

I bought "Triple Grip" anchors as they appeared to work for thinner surfaces. I installed one successfully but attempts to get into other holes are failing. The anchor starts spinning as I drill into it (usually about halfway in) and typically rips into 2 pieces.

I also have toggle bolts that I can use, but I am wary of this because the 1/2" hole I would need to drill. We're renting and would not be here long.

Am I not installing the triple grip anchors correctly? Is there a better solution?

It occurred to me that a neodymium magnet on the bottom of the panel would provide a very secure anchor but this would be a custom fabrication and probably outside the scope of this project :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold the bracket on the face of the metal panel and mark the screw holes with a sharpie. Drill a small pilot hole at the marks. Then drill a hole that is slightly smaller than the shank of the screw you will use to install the bracket. Then fasten the bracket with the screws into the pre-drilled holes. You don't need any anchors with this method.